# how to scrape website data after clicking More button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping using BS4 + selenium. Website link is [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1010231-d1065009-Reviews-Radisson_Blu_Resort_Spa_Alibaug-Alibaug_Raigad_District_Maharashtra.html)

The review text has a More SPAN, on which click some more text is loaded into same div using AJAX.

But my code output the review text before the More button click by selenium.

How can I wait to scrape till More button click using selenium

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def openUrl(link):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(link)

    elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='taLnk ulBlueLinks']")
    elem1.click()
    html_source = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
    foundDiv = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "review-container"})
    for reviewContainer in foundDiv:

        ratingText = reviewContainer.select_one(".partial_entry").text
        print(ratingText)

openUrl("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1010231-d1065009-Reviews-Radisson_Blu_Resort_Spa_Alibaug-Alibaug_Raigad_District_Maharashtra.html")
```

But BS4 scrape data without waiting for More button click.

Please help

[image]

Comment: Can you use on the items in the list at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions to check for the availability of the page?

Comment: Page and element is available. On More click some extra text is fetched through Ajax, and added to existing text. I need to pause python code for some time till new data is populated.

Answer (score 0):

See an example of WebDriverWait below.

```
driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1010231-d1065009-Reviews-Radisson_Blu_Resort_Spa_Alibaug-Alibaug_Raigad_District_Maharashtra.html')
moreButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")
moreButton.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-reviewid='493434022'] div.loadingShade")))

html_source = driver.page_source
print(html_source)
```

Comment: I didnt try it yet, but div[data-reviewid='493434022'], is present all the time, it s the clicking of MORE link, extra data is appended into the same div. No new element is created.

Comment: Anyway I solved it without Selenium, by simulating the AJAX requests. Thanks for your suggestions though

Comment: @raju I'm sorry. I don't understand your comments. The `div[data-reviewid='493434022']` is just an example element of a review. My code click "More" and then wait until  `div[data-reviewid='493434022'] div.loadingShade` has disappeared, and then get the updated content including the extra data which has been appended. Could you clarify what your question is?